# Android- Firebase onChildChanged

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like my child data to update in real-time when I change the data. I am new in Java programming. The error was when i tried to set the my list arraylist with new child data, there is a error for wrong 2nd argument. The Following is my code...Appreciate any helps, Thank in advance.

```
public class OverallResultFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "OverallResultFragment";

    private ArrayList<Booth> list =  new ArrayList<>();;
    private ArrayList<Booth> mkeys = new ArrayList<>();
    ProductListAdapter adapter = null;
    private Firebase mRef;
    ListView gridView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_votingresult, container, false);
        mRef = new Firebase("https://myfb.firebaseio.com/myfb");
        gridView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        adapter = new ProductListAdapter(this.getContext(), R.layout.list_product_item, list);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


        com.firebase.client.Query Queryref = mRef.orderByValue();
        Queryref.addChildEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                String boothname = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                list.add(new Booth(boothname, value));

                mkeys.add(new Booth(boothname));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                String boothname = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                int index = mkeys.indexOf(boothname);
                list.set(index, value);//error on "value" -> wrong 2nd argument.
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
}
```

And this is my Booth class:

```
 public class Booth {
       String rating;
        String Boothname;
        int index;


        public Booth(String boothname, String Rating){
          this.Boothname = boothname;
            this.rating= Rating;
        }

        public String getBoothName(){
            return Boothname;
        }
        public void setProductId(String boothname){
            this.Boothname = boothname;
        }

        public String getRating(){
            return rating;
        }
        public void setRating(String rating){
            this.rating = rating;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is because it's not a string type 2nd Argument.

Replace that line with this:

```
  list.set(index, new Booth(boothname,value));
```

It will work for you
Thanks and happy coding.

**EDITED**

Replace this line :

```
  int index = mkeys.indexOf(boothname);
```

With this:

```
 int index = mkeys.indexOf(new Booth(boothname));
```

It will solve your crash issue.

Comment: this will take away the compile error but logically incorrect `int index = mkeys.indexOf(boothname);` , here `index` will always be `-1` and produce crash

Comment: Sorry I didn't get. What you want to say?

Comment: oh i didn't see the complete code of OP,my bad , your code still won't work

Comment: Now where is problem and what actually??...I don't think there is any syntax or logical error left.but instead tell me...I will solve

Comment: ok , `override equals and hashcode` in `Booth` to make it work

Comment: @ankitpatidar Hi, thx for the answer. It fix the syntax error but my app crash now when I update the child value from firebase